# Outputting PSBound Parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'd like to output the values of whatever parameters have been passed to my script for including in an email.

I've tried this:

```
foreach ($psbp in $PSBoundParameters)
{
    $messageBody += $psbp | out-string + "`r`n"
}
```

But it didn't work.  Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Thanks to both David and Shay.  It was passing of the get-enumerator that I needed.  Also, this page:

http://halr9000.com/article/912

gave me the form I was really wanting to do as well.

Answer (score 8):

$PSBoundParameters is a hash table, use GetEnumerator to unfold its items

```
foreach($psbp in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator())
{
    "Key={0} Value={1}" -f $psbp.Key,$psbp.Value
}




function Get-PSBoundParameters
{
    [CmdletBinding()]    
    Param($param1,$param2,$param3)

    foreach($psbp in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator())
    {
            "Key={0} Value={1}" -f $psbp.Key,$psbp.Value
    }
}


PS> Get-PSBoundParameters p1 p2 p3 | ft -a

Key=param1 Value=p1
Key=param2 Value=p2
Key=param3 Value=p3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test 
{
    param($a, $b)

    $psboundparameters.Values
    $psboundparameters.Keys
}


test "Hello" "World"
```